How to display a concatenated (value + %) in a bar graph in excel
I have a table in Excel
Deployed  120
Not Deployed Yet 10
Not Supported 70

I would like to create a bar graph with the above. However, while the three segments of the bar graph should be proportional to the three values, the labels need to also include the %. Is that possible?
eg:
"Deployed" -> 120 (60%)
"Not Deployed Yet " -> 10 (5%)
"Not Deployet Yet" -> 70 (35%)

I tried creating a column concatenating the number and %, but the bar graph gets messed up with the combined value

You may create a pivot table chart.

Select the table, then create a chart. Insert 2 numbers fields as "Values".
Select one in the Values area > Click the dropdown arrow > Click "Value Field Settings" > Click on the second tab "Show Values As" > Click "% of Grand Total", and "OK".

Then select the pivot table, create a chart and show "Data Labels".
